# Is Y a compact subset?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

$X$ compact topological space, $f\colon X\to X$ continuous

> > Is then $Y:=\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}f^n(X)\subset X$ compact?

Edit (based on the comments I got below):

The assumption that $X$ is Hausdorff is needed. So let's assume that.
For each $n\geq 1$, $f^{n}(X)$ is compact and thus closed, and hence $Y$ is closed as intersection of closed sets.

Since $Y\subset X$ is closed and $X$ is compact, it follows that $Y$ is compact.

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: I am only missing a "proof" why $f^n(X)^C, n\geq 1$, is open.

Comment: Is it given that $\mathrm{Im}(f^{n}(X)) = X$? If this is the case I think your proof is correct.

Comment: @LaurentHayez No, I think this is not given.

Comment: @Salamo I think I saw the post just before the edit, and it was written that $f^n(X)^c = \varnothing$, that's why I asked. Neither would I see why $f^n(X)^c$ is open.

Comment: You need to use (or prove) two facts: first, that if $K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, then $f(K)$ is compact. Second, that an arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed.

Comment: $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact so $f(X)$ is compact and therefore closed...

Comment: @PedroM. Isn't a compact set closed only for metric spaces or in a Hausdorff-space? *confused*

Comment: @Salamo: Not only for metric spaces, it works for [Hausdorff topological spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space). Is $X$ not assumed to be Hausdorff?

Comment: @Salamo If $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $A \subset X$, if $A$ is compact then $A$ is closed in $X$. If $X$ is compact and $A$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is compact. If $X$ is metrizable and $A$ is compact, then $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Hyothesis "Hausdorff" is needed, at least for this proof.  (Of course in Bourbaki, "compact" includes Hausdorff in the definition.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I can assume that it is Hausdorff! ok, I'll edit my question then.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is fine if $X$ is Hausdorff. For the sake of completeness, here’s a non-Hausdorff counterexample. Let $X=\Bbb N\times\{0,1\}$, and for $i\in\{0,1\}$ let $X_i=\Bbb N\times\{i\}$. Points of $X_0$ are isolated. A set $U\subseteq X$ is an open nbhd of $\langle n,1\rangle\in X_1$ if and only if $\langle n,1\rangle\in U$ and $X\setminus U$ is finite. Then $X$ is compact and $T_1$ but not Hausdorff. Let

$$f:X\to X:\langle n,i\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle n,i\rangle,&\text{if }i=0\\
\langle n+1,i\rangle,&\text{if }i=1\;;
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is not just continuous, but in fact a homeomorphism of $X$ onto $X\setminus\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}$. However,

$$Y=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}f[X]=X_0\;,$$

which is an infinite discrete space and therefore not compact.

Intuitively, I just started with a convergent sequence together with its limit point and replaced the limit point by a countably infinite set with the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology). The map $f$ leaves the points of the sequence alone, but each iteration of it eliminates one more of the limit points.